# To create element dynamically and want to open it with a dialog (close event if clicked outside of dialog) in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to open a `dialog` in which I need to append a div element(which should also be created as dialog gets opened). dialog open/close event is as: 
Need to open it on button click, 
Need to close it on clicking outside of the dialog.

please help me to get over this problem.

### js:

```
function clickFunc() {
        'use strict';
        let child = document.createElement("DIV");
        child.innerHTML = '<div  id="fnameId">Hi I am a new Div</div>';
        body.appendChild(child);
        //here this div with id='frameId', need to be shown in dialog box.
}
```

### html:

```
<button onclick="clickFunc();">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like you want a modal [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: @OmriAttiya i have edited my answer. in which i have created a div element ,  i need to popup this div element in a dialog box and that `dialog box should also be created on firing clickFunc()`

Comment: @RobMoll yes but after clicking to all elements need to be created dynamically

Comment: so create the modal on the fly and display it, it shouldn't be a problem